# Transforming null into array.length = 0

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

Probably a noob Question: On my server, there is a filter which returns all available options if  an array of the filter object has length.0 for certain options.

Now if say i have an input "All Options" from the user side, this option when clicked must somehow tell the array to have length.0, so the server returns all options .
I tried to set the Input  to

```
  <mat-option [value]= null >Alle</mat-option>
```

But that results in an array that has the value null instead of no length at all.

I also tried

```
If (data.array[1] == undefined){
data.array.length == 0
}
```

But that did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the value to null and then do it like this:

```
if (!data.array) {
    data.array = [];
}
```